# How to handle if one column value is null then use another column value in freemarker

Tags: freemarker

For suppose i have two columns drillTime and drillDateTime.
Condition:
If drillTime value is there print drillTime or if it is null print drillDateTime.

```
Our Code:[#if dmd.drillTime??]${dmd.drillTime!""}[#elseif dmd.drillDateTime??]${dmd.drillDateTime!""}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's shorter solution:

```
${dmd.drillTime!dmd.drillDateTime!}
```